# document.write writes 'object' instead of text

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var all=[

{origin:"asian", type:"veg",time:10,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xye54WGqcBM"},
{origin:"asian", type:"veg",time:10,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP7AYsqcT1k"},
{origin:"asian", type:"veg",time:30,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEF0HaBP4as"},
{origin:"asian", type:"veg",time:30,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYDRX83-IRo"},
{origin:"asian", type:"nonveg",time:10,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2CVlvSSFO4"},
{origin:"asian", type:"nonveg",time:10,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6xFRlG5Qxg"},
{origin:"asian", type:"nonveg",time:30,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17F3zVsSuyU"},
{origin:"asian", type:"nonveg",time:30,link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_6aMZwf9CU"}]

function replace(){
  var x = all.toString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="projCSS.css">
    <script src="proj.js"></script>
    <title>Recefoods</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="demo">hello</p>
    <button onclick="replace()"> TRY </button>


</body>


</html>
```

The function prints Object,object instead of the origin, type, time and the link... what's going on?
I am not sure what the problam is or why it doesn't print what i want it to, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() instead of toString()

Comment: An object can't be turned into a string implicitly. Call `JSON.stringify` on it instead, with a 3rd parameter if you want it to look pretty